# Estou com um erro no scanf

Tags: c, input, buffer, scanf, quebras-de-linha

Eu tenho que ler N linhas com um dos seguintes 3 formatos:

- "**P k**": a letra **P** seguida do k sendo k um número inteiro;
- "**A k**": a letra **A** seguida do k sendo k um número inteiro;
- "**Q**": a letra **Q**.

Como não sei se a pessoa vai por P/A ou Q primeiro só tenho que ler uma letra.

Caso a letra seja Q faço o código respectivo à letra. Se for P/A ainda tenho que ler um inteiro e depois fazer o código da respectiva letra P/A e o respectivo número.

O meu problema é que faço `scanf` para a primeira letra desta forma mais ao menos:

```
for(idx = 0; idx < N ; idx++)
scanf("%c",&opc);
```

Dentro do `for` tenho mais algum código. O problema é o seguinte. A primeira vez corre bem. A segunda vez que ele chega ao `scanf` do `char` o compilador põe automaticamente o character de código ASCII 10 representativo da quebra de linha.

Isto acontece porque o `scanf` não limpa o buffer de ENTERs por isso fiz isto:

```
for(idx = 0; idx < N ; idx++)
scanf("%c\n",&opc);*
```

Acrescentei um `\n` nos `scanf` para ele de certa forma consumir a quebra de linha.

Desta forma surge-me outro erro que é: (exemplo) caso o primeiro input seja Q por exemplo ele pede-me duas o Q para o ler só uma vez.

Portanto meto um Q e não acontece nada. Ponho o segundo que aí ele avança e segue normalmente.

Comment: coloca um `\n` antes do `%c`. `scanf("\n%c", &opc);`

Comment: A melhor (mais segura, mais controlavel) opcao para obter input do utilizador é com o `fgets()` possivelmente seguido de remover o ENTER e/ou `sscanf()` para isolar partes do input.

Answer (score 1):

O conversor `"%c"` (ao contrario de muitos outros conversores do `scanf()`) nao ignora espacos em branco. Se o input tiver espacos (ou ENTERs ou TABs) esses espacos serao atribuidos a variavel especificada.

Para ignorar espacos em branco, acrescenta um espaco na string de formato:

```
if (scanf(" %c", &x) != 1) /* error */;
//         ^ ignora zero ou mais espacos em branco (ou ENTERs, TABs)
```

---

Meter o espaco em branco depois do conversor tem um efeito bastante espantoso para quem nao esta a espera

Suponhamos que o codigo era o seguinte e que o utilizador digita "Q [ENTER] [ENTER] [ENTER] 42 [ENTER]"

```
scanf("%c ");
```

O `"%c"` "apanha" o 'Q' e o scanf() salta para o espaco em branco. Esta parte "apanha" o primeiro [ENTER], o segundo [ENTER], p terceiro [ENTER] e para apenas quando chega ao "4".
O "4" (e o "2" e o [ENTER]) ficam no *buffer* a espera de proxima instrucao de leitura.